# iterate through classes with same name in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

in the website I'm testing there is a table with 5 nested classes with the same names.

I need to validate that under the table there is exactly 5 classes but they are all the same name.

How can I iterate through the 5 classes?

I've attached a picture to better explain what I mean[image]

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, all I had to do is to make sure there are 15 items total in 3 lists, so 5 items in each list. I needed to iterate in order to make sure nothing is missing and with the help of your answers I found the answer:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By
            .className("top-performer-item"));

    assertEquals(15, element.size());
    driver.quit();
```

I didn't choose any particular answer because it was the help of you both that got me there. I thank you very much!

Comment: FYI, you didn't iterate anything.  You measured the size of the result set.  If your question had said "_I have to make sure there are 15 items total in 3 lists_", you'd have gotten the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "iterate", but one possibility would be to use XPath's child-position selector.  For example, `findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'list-container')]/div[contains(@class, 'list-0')]/div[2]"))` will find the second of the "top-performer-item" divs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below snippet :

```
int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(By.cssSelector(".list-container > .list-0 > .top-performer-item"));
  for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++) {
    getElementWithIndex(locator, pos).doWhateverYouWantWithTheElement()
  }

  public int getNumberOfElementsFound(By by) {
      return webDriver.findElements(by).size();
  }

  public WebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int pos) {
      return webDriver.findElements(by).get(pos);
  }
```